# JSON file rendered in HTML using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, json

I'm trying to render a JSON file as an HTML table using `$.getJSON`, but I'm having some trouble.

I've created a very simple script, which should generate the relevant HTML table tags, and look at each row in the JSON file to render within those tags.

Below is the code from my HTML file:

```
<html> <head> <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"> </script>

<script>

    $(function() {


   var people = [];

   $.getJSON('people.json', function(data) {
       $.each(data.person, function(i, f) {
          var tblRow = "<tr>" + "<td>" + f.firstName + "</td>" +
           "<td>" + f.lastName + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.job + "</td>" + "<td>" + f.roll + "</td>" + "</tr>"
           $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata tbody");
     });

   });

}); </script> </head>

<body>

<div class="wrapper"> <div class="profile">    <table id= "userdata" border="2">   <thead>
            <th>First Name</th>
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email Address</th>
            <th>City</th>
        </thead>
      <tbody>

       </tbody>    </table>

</div> </div>
```

And below is the code from the people.JSON (referenced) file:

```
{
   "person": [
       {
           "firstName": "Clark",
           "lastName": "Kent",
           "job": "Reporter",
           "roll": 20
       },
       {
           "firstName": "Bruce",
           "lastName": "Wayne",
           "job": "Playboy",
           "roll": 30
       },
       {
           "firstName": "Peter",
           "lastName": "Parker",
           "job": "Photographer",
           "roll": 40
       }
   ]
}
```

For some reason, the JSON is not rendering between the tbody tags!! Driving me crazy. Anyone have any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: It seems to be working fine here - http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/d99aE/ And Bruce Wayne is a philanthropist, not a playboy :)

Comment: have you tryed $(tblRow).appendTo("#userdata > tbody")?

Comment: That isn't needed @faby, especially since there is only one tbody for #userdata in this case.

Comment: can you describe the error? is it rendered? Or is it rendered in a wrong place?

Comment: The error is that I don't see any data rendered in my HTML page (locally). I just see the HTML printed for the table headers. Also @JayBlanchard, I see you got it working by directly inserting the JSON into the JavaScript, but this isn't what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to load a JSON file that's generated from a web service, and then load the JSON file into the HTML page. This is why I'm using "getJSON"